# SuiteScript 2.0 Two actions on submit button

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I need add two action into submit button, I succeed on that but because I can't find correct function from API, there is two buttons. Like this

[image: What i get]

I want it like this:

[image: Example working buttoin]

What I have tried

```
form.addSubmitButton({ label: 'Action 1'});
form.addSubmitButton({ label: 'Action 2'});
```

And

```
form.addSubmitButton({ id : 'action', label: 'Action 1'});
form.addSubmitButton({ id : 'action', label: 'Action 2'});
```

And

```
form.addSubmitButton({ id: 'action1', label: 'Action 1'});
var test = form.addSubmitButton({ id: 'action2', label: 'Action 2'});
test.isHidden = true;
```

Comment: Just a thought...  Can you not have a single action that runs a function.  Then in that function call your two different actions that you need to perform?

Answer (score 0):

Something that worked for me was adding the name attribute to each submit button using client script. That way when the user clicks it will send the name as a parameter.